# debugging JavaScript runtime syntax errors

Tags: error-handling, cordova, push-notification, syntax-error, phonegap-plugins

Short: I am looking for a way to get the text of the script that was evaluated and caused a syntax error from within the context of window.onerror.

Long:
The full scenario includes a phone gap application and the PushNotifications plugins.
When a push message is sent to the device a javascript error is caught using window.onerror.

with the text "SyntaxtError: Expected token '}'"
the reported line number is 1 (is it is usually when dealing with `EVAL`uated code.

The way the plugin executs its code is by using:

```
 NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@);", self.callback, jsonStr];
 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

I belive but not  100% sure that this is the code PhoneGap Build are pushing 
more code can be seen in here https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/PushPlugin.m#L177

the `self.callback` is a string passed by me to the plugin and jsonStr is (supposed to be) an object describing the push message.

when I tried to pass as the parameter that ends up being `self.callback` the string `alert('a');//` then I did get the alert and no syntax error. ad now I am trying to understand what does jsonStr gets evaluated to so that maybe I can find a way around it or figure out if its my fault somehow (maybe for the content I am sending in the push notification....)

I also tried to look at the last item of the `$('script')` collection of the document hopeing that maybe stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString generates a new script block but that does not seem to be the case.

further more in the window.onerror I also tried to get the caller 
using `var c=window.onerror.caller||window.onerror.arguments.caller;` but this returns undefined.

As I stated before - I am looking for ideas on how to determine what exactly is causing the syntax error possibly by getting a hold of the entire block of script being evaluated when the syntax error happened.